# Rails, static page for newest model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have a model called "Gamesession", this will take some variabels to generate different configurations to a game(i'm playing in real life) each time I play. So I want a static page called play.html.erb to always be the place where the newest "active" session is. Right now I'm deleting all the previous sessions everytime I make a new. So that I can use the gamsession#index. Is there a better way to only have one "active" gamesession on the same page(play.html) each time? Please explain in detail if you have the time, I'm very new at rails. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the last created one

`@latest_game_session = GameSession.order(created_at: :desc).first`

Comment: Oh my, it was that simple! Thank you so much!